# 2 cards in a row in one reaction block

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need 2 maps, but an incomprehensible error comes up: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data-src'). Thank you in advance

```
<Auto play={true} cancelOnInteraction={false} interval={10000} bullets={false} buttons={false}>
                {dataKZ.map((val, idx) => {
                    return <div key={idx}>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>Аты-жөні: {val.ret_fio ? val.ret_fio : 'белгілі емес'}</h2>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>Билет: {val.ret_letter_code ? val.ret_letter_code : 'белгілі емес'}</h2>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>Күй: {val.ret_status_kz ? val.ret_status_kz : 'белгілі емес'}</h2>
                    </div>
                })}
                {dataRU.map((val, idx) => {
                    return <div key={idx}>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>{val.ret_fio ? val.ret_fio : 'не указан'}</h2>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>{val.ret_letter_code ? val.ret_letter_code : 'не указан'}</h2>
                        <h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>{val.ret_ru_status ? val.ret_ru_status : 'не указан'}</h2>
                    </div>
                })}
            </Auto>
```

I need to output to two pyramids, I still have an array in my head with 2 subarrays, another composition couldn’t do it.

Comment: please share a stackblitz, error seems to be coming from elsewhere!